# Quick way to generate the Shepp-Logan phantom

Tags: performance-tuning, image

I have some very old code for generating a [Shepp-Logan phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp%E2%80%93Logan_phantom):

```
SheppLoganData = {
{{0, 0}, {0.92, 0.69}, 90°, 2}, {{0, -0.0184}, {0.874, 0.6624}, 90°, -0.9},
{{0.22, 0}, {0.31, 0.11}, 72°, -0.1}, {{-0.22, 0}, {0.41, 0.16}, 108°, -0.1},
{{0, 0.35}, {0.25, 0.21}, 90°, 0.3}, {{0, 0.1}, {0.046, 0.046}, 0, 0.3},
{{0, -0.1}, {0.046, 0.046}, 0, 0.3}, {{-0.08, -0.605}, {0.046, 0.023}, 0, 0.3},
{{0.06, -0.605}, {0.046, 0.023}, 90°, 0.3}, {{0, -0.605}, {0.023, 0.023}, 0, 0.3}
};

DensityPlot[Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ 
SheppLoganData], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
Frame -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

[image]

(The previous version used RotationMatrix2D from the Rotations package, but I have updated it to use the current built-in.)

This is very *slow*, however. Image is apparently what is used today to represent images in Mathematica, so is there any way to adapt my old code to produce an Image of the Shepp-Logan phantom for a specified size (e.g. a 1024×1024 image)? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What do the numbers under "Gray Level" mean in the table in Wikipedia?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I had a look at the [original paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TNS.1974.6499235); it seems those values get added up whenever a given point is within any of those ten ellipses.

Comment: You could also do the following: take the symbolic expression you generate for this: `Total[#4 Boole[norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ 
  SheppLoganData]`.  It may be better to define `norm = Sqrt[#.#]&` instead of `Norm` to save some unneeded `Abs` calls.  Take the resulting expression, and copy-paste it inside of `cf = Compile[{x,y}, ...]`.  Then use this function as `Array[cf, {512, 512}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] // Transpose // Reverse // 
  Image // ImageAdjust`.  It's faster than my answer, and fairly straightforward too.

Comment: If instead of compiling, you could take the time to rewrite this in vectorizable form, it would be faster still.

Comment: @Szabolcs, many thanks for your contribution. Is there any way Melania Black original code could run faster while retaining "DensityPlot"?

Answer (score 10):

#### Using Graphics

Using the data supplied by yourself, you could do something along the lines of:

```
grs = Graphics[{White, Rotate[Disk[#1, #2], #3]}, Background -> Black,
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] & @@@ SheppLoganData;

ImageAdjust@Image@Total@MapThread[
    #2 ImageData[
       ColorConvert[
        Rasterize[Style[#, Antialiasing -> False], "Image", 
         ImageSize -> 512],
        "Grayscale"],
       "Real"] &,
    {
     grs,
     SheppLoganData[[All, -1]]
     }
    ]
```

It's not fast, but neither is it unbearably slow.

[image]

---

#### Alternative method

Take the expression you wrote yourself, and use it in a compiled function.  I will make a small change and replace `Norm` by `norm = Sqrt[#.#]&` to get rid of some `Abs` calls.

```
Total[#4 Boole[norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ 
   SheppLoganData] // Simplify

0.3 Boole[22.6757 x^2 + 16. (-0.35 + y)^2 < 1] + 
 0.3 Boole[472.59 x^2 + 472.59 (-0.1 + y)^2 < 1] - 
 0.1 Boole[
   0.0351981 + 1. x^2 + 0.123325 y + 0.228447 y^2 < 
    0.44 x + 0.560566 x y] - 
 0.1 Boole[
   0.0205452 + 0.44 x + 1. x^2 + 0.119275 y + 0.542158 x y + 
     0.253783 y^2 < 0] + 2 Boole[2.1004 x^2 + 1.18147 y^2 < 1] - 
 0.9 Boole[2.27908 x^2 + 1.30911 (0.0184 + y)^2 < 1] + 
 0.3 Boole[472.59 x^2 + 472.59 (0.1 + y)^2 < 1] + 
 0.3 Boole[1890.36 (-0.06 + x)^2 + 472.59 (0.605 + y)^2 < 1] + 
 0.3 Boole[1890.36 x^2 + 1890.36 (0.605 + y)^2 < 1] + 
 0.3 Boole[472.59 (0.08 + x)^2 + 1890.36 (0.605 + y)^2 < 1]
```

In order to avoid having to deal with the subtleties of code generation, I just copy this and paste it into a compiled function:

```
cf = Compile[{x, y},
   0.3` Boole[22.675736961451246` x^2 + 16.` (-0.35` + y)^2 < 1] + 
    0.3` Boole[
      472.5897920604915` x^2 + 472.5897920604915` (-0.1` + y)^2 < 
       1] - 0.1` Boole[
      0.03519805880091542` + 1.` x^2 + 0.1233245922675553` y + 
        0.22844664024299033` y^2 < 
       0.44` x + 0.5605663284888875` x y] - 
    0.1` Boole[
      0.02054517798250305` + 0.4400000000000001` x + 1.` x^2 + 
        0.11927486660565205` y + 0.5421584845711455` x y + 
        0.2537828638062259` y^2 < 0] + 
    2 Boole[2.100399075824407` x^2 + 1.1814744801512287` y^2 < 1] - 
    0.9` Boole[
      2.2790788583164137` x^2 + 1.3091129973974835` (0.0184` + y)^2 < 
       1] + 0.3` Boole[
      472.5897920604915` x^2 + 472.5897920604915` (0.1` + y)^2 < 1] + 
    0.3` Boole[
      1890.359168241966` (-0.06` + x)^2 + 
        472.5897920604915` (0.605` + y)^2 < 1] + 
    0.3` Boole[
      1890.359168241966` x^2 + 1890.359168241966` (0.605` + y)^2 < 
       1] + 0.3` Boole[
      472.5897920604915` (0.08` + x)^2 + 
        1890.359168241966` (0.605` + y)^2 < 1]
   ];
```

We can verify that it will make no callbacks to the main evaluator.

Now instead of using `ListDensityPlot`, we use it with `Array`:

```
Array[cf, {512, 512}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] // Transpose // Reverse // 
  Image // ImageAdjust
```

This took half a second on my machine.

[image]