# What is the meaning of this code section?

Tags: function-construction, boolean-computation, rotation

I like to know the meaning of this:

```
Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ 
Data]
```

I need to make a slight modification to a code for generating Shepp Logan phantom and I need to be sure I am going about it in the right manner.

Note (taken from this [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119705/quick-way-to-generate-the-shepp-logan-phantom)):

```
Data = {{{0, 0}, {0.92, 0.69}, 90°, 2}, {{0, -0.0184}, {0.874, 0.6624}, 90°,-0.9},{{0.22, 0}, {0.31, 0.11}, 72°, -0.1}, {{-0.22, 0}, {0.41, 0.16}, 108°, -0.1},{{0, 0.35}, {0.25, 0.21}, 90°, 0.3}, {{0, 0.1}, {0.046, 0.046}, 0, 0.3},{{0, -0.1}, {0.046, 0.046}, 0, 0.3}, {{-0.08, -0.605}, {0.046, 0.023}, 0, 0.3},{{0.06, -0.605}, {0.046, 0.023}, 90°, 0.3}, {{0, -0.605}, {0.023, 0.023}, 0, 0.3}};
```

A table representing this table is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqkesy0mn3xu170/2D_SheppLogan.xlsx?dl=0)! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code defines a function,

```
#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] &
```

applies it to each element of `Data`, and finally sums the results for all elements of `Data`.  Because there are four variable in this function (`#1`, etc.), the elements of `Data` must themselves be lists of four elements.  For instance,

```
Data = {{{1.27304,2.73124}, 2.87282, 2.85453, 1.21836}, 
        {{4.44383,5.74962}, 4.78388, 1.48409, 0.19928}, 
        {{5.35696,4.73832}, 2.24427, 6.20758, 3.08224}}
```

`x` and `y` also must be defined.  For instance,

```
x = 1; y = 3;
```

Applying the function to the first element of `Data`,

```
1.21836 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - {1.27304, 2.73124}).RotationMatrix[2.85453]/2.87282]^2 < 1]
(* 1.21836 *)
```

(See Mathematica documentation for `Boole`, `Norm`, `Dot`, and `RotationMatrix`.)

`@@@` applies the function to every such element of `Data`, and `Total` sums the results.  (See Mathematica documentation for `Apply` and `Total`.)

```
Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ Data]
(* 1.41764 *)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind and detailed answer @bbgodfrey. I have added the definition of "Data" to my question. Would this produce any different narrative?

Comment: @Dean  No, it should not.  However, please provide me with your values for `{x,y}`, so that I can take a harder look.

Comment: I have inserted a link to the table respresenting this data as a modification to my question. However, the angle is in radians and not in degrees as in the above data. If you need me to change them to degress, please let me know. Many thanks!

Comment: @Dean  Although the table to which you linked contain columns labeled x and y, they are not the `x` and `y` appearing in your question.  Instead, they ae the `#1` appearing in the function.  Your other link, to a StackExchange question, leave `x` and  `y` undefined, which causes the function in your question to produce a lengthy block of code, which can be evaluated later for various values of `{x, y}`.  Nothing is wrong with this approach either.

Comment: Alright @bbgodfrey, really appreciate your kind exchange. Actually, the complete code is (I am just trying to understand the function on which DensityPlot is operating): DensityPlot[Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ 
Data], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
Frame -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 500]

Comment: @Dean  For reasons I do not yet understand, `f = Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@ Data]; DensityPlot[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]` gives a much better plot than `DensityPlot[Total[#4 Boole[Norm[({x, y} - #1).RotationMatrix[#3]/#2]^2 < 1] & @@@Data], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]`.  Of course, it is faster too.

Comment: @Dean  If you use the code involving `f` in my last comment, include the option, `, Exclusions -> None` to eliminate the spurious white outlines around the ellipses in the plot.  As a bonus, it further reduces run time.

Comment: Wao!! Many thanks @bbgodfrey. I am currently running the code.

Comment: @Dean  By the way, it does not matter whether you use "Mesh -> False".

Comment: Alright @bbgodfrey!